# como mostrar a matriz em forma de matriz e não os números dispostos um do lado do outro?

Tags: pascal

Eu fiz mas não deu certo:

```
program teste;  
 uses crt;  
 var  
   iMat: array [1..3,1..3] of integer;  
   iLin, iCol: integer;  
 begin  
   write ('Digite os números da matriz: ');  
   for iLin:=1 to 3 do  
   begin  
    for iCol:=1 to 3 do  
      read (iMat[iLin,iCol]);  
   end;  
 clrscr;  
   for iLin:=1 to 3 do  
   begin  
    for iCol:=1 to 3 do  
    gotoxy (iCol,iLin); write (iMat[iLin,iCol]);  
   end;  
 readkey;  
 end.
```

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei o seguinte erro:

```
for iLin:=1 to 3 do
begin
for iCol:=1 to 3 do
gotoxy (iCol,iLin); write (iMat[iLin,iCol]);
end
```

Faltou um Begin antes do GotoXY.

Corrigindo:

```
program teste;  
 uses crt;  
 var  
   iMat: array [1..3,1..3] of integer;  
   iLin, iCol: integer;  
 begin  
  ClrScr;  
  write ('Digite os números da matriz: ');  
  for iLin:=1 to 3 do  
  begin  
   for iCol:=1 to 3 do  
   begin  
    Write ('(',iLin,',',iCol,')= ');  
    ReadLn (iMat[iLin,iCol]);  
   end;  
  end;  
  ClrScr;  
  for iLin:=1 to 3 do  
  begin  
   for iCol:=1 to 3 do  
   begin  
    gotoxy (iCol,iLin); write (iMat[iLin,iCol]);  
   end;  
  end;  
  readkey;  
 end.
```

Answer (score 4):

Troque o comando `write()` por `writeln()` na hora de escrever o resultado.

Mude:

```
write (iMat[iLin,iCol]);
```

Para:

```
writeln (iMat[iLin,iCol]);
```

Comment: Para o caso do colega, sempre daria nova linha o que exibiria apenas uma linha, e não em forma de tabela/matriz.

Answer (score 2):

Assim: Um for para linha e outro para coluna (dentro).

```
Program HelloWorld(output);
var
  matriz: array [1..3,1..3] of integer;
  linha, coluna: integer; 
begin
  matriz[1,1] := 1;
  matriz[1,2] := 2;
  matriz[1,3] := 3;
  matriz[2,1] := 1;
  matriz[2,2] := 2;
  matriz[2,3] := 3;
  matriz[3,1] := 1;
  matriz[3,2] := 2;
  matriz[3,3] := 3;

  for linha := 1 to 3 do
      begin

        for coluna :=1 to 3 do
            begin

                write(matriz[coluna, linha]);
                write('    ');

            end;

        writeln('');

      end;


end.
```